# ERROR cannot read property of.......undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I got this error in console:`ProductFormComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

```js
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product = {}; 
 
  
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute, 
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories(); 


    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
   }

   save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

 
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input  #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                    Title is required.
                </div>
```

Error is in my HTML template on product.title. Product is a problem because when the application is rendering, product is empty. I added an empty object {} to the product but it didn't help. Recently I added `ngIf="product"` on my template and now I get `404()not found`.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I can*t reproduce your problem is not reproducible. Can you provide a link or a **working** code snippet that shows **your** error (e.g. with jsfiddle)?

Comment: I can show my entire code on github.Is that ok?

Comment: https://github.com/filipristic23/aplikacija2

Comment: I won't install the hole server on my machine. Narrow the problem down to a code snippet, so it is comprehensible and the error is reproducible. Otherwise it is impossible to help you. Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)